# Why do you think I know that? vs. Why do you think THAT I know that?

Tags: grammar

Which of the following is the correct or more correct?

> 1. Why do you think I know that?
> 2. Why do you think **that** I know that?

Answer (score 1):

Your both examples mean the same thing, #2 being just a little bit clearer.

The basic rule is that the conjunction **that** can be omitted as long as the meaning is not affected by doing so. But, as a sentence gets longer and more complex is better that the conjunction(s) **that** be left there for clarity's sake.

Comment: +1 In this particular instance, however, I think most speakers would intuitively incline toward the version without the complementizer *that*, because *that* is employed in a different and more emphatic sense at the end of the sentence.