# Is “that” required in “The music company was afraid that...”?

Tags: sentence-construction, ellipsis, clauses

> Sentence:The music company was afraid the accelerating decline of sales of compact discs would not be compensated by increased internet revenue.
>
> Solution:The music company was afraid **that** the accelerating decline of sales of compact discs would not be compensated by increased internet revenue.

I was given the following example. By using "that", the sentence is corrected.

I can't tell why and what's the difference in meaning with or without the word "that".

This was the given explanation:

> "The original sentence has one independent clause (the music company was afraid of something) and then includes another main verb (would not be . . . revenue), but there is no conjunction to create a compound verb, so that second verb doesn’t have the same subject (company). Logically, the subject for the second verb should be the decline of sales, but this noun is in a prep phrase, so it can’t function as a subject of the sentence. One way to fix the sentence is to replace the preposition of with that: The music company was afraid THAT the accelerating decline of sales of compact discs would not be compensated by increased internet revenue. "

Can anyone please help to explain this further?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do you think I know that? vs. Why do you think THAT I know that?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56138/why-do-you-think-i-know-that-vs-why-do-you-think-that-i-know-that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **The music company  was afraid (that) the accelerating decline of sales of compact discs would not be compensated by increased internet revenue**

I think *that* in the sentence is a conjunction and its use optional.The sentence  with or without **that**  makes no difference in meaning and the sentence  is  grammatically correct to me.

Here is a link which shows the usage.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/afraid

Answer (score -2):

The sentence is missing something that defines the causal relationship between "the accelerating decline of sales" and "compact discs would not be compensated [...]"

You could say as suggested:

> The music company was afraid **that** the accelerating decline of sales of compact discs would not be compensated by increased internet revenue.

Or some others:

> The music company was afraid **of** the accelerating decline **because** sales of compact discs would not be compensated by increased internet revenue.
>
> The music company was afraid the accelerating decline **was caused by** sales of compact discs **not being** compensated by increased internet revenue.
>
> The music company **feared** the accelerating decline **due to** sales of compact discs **not being** compensated by increased internet revenue.

Comment: I think to a greater or lesser extent, all three of your revised versions *alter the meaning* of the original (which is syntactically and idiomatically fine as it stands). The second one i n particular represents a pretty radical shift in meaning - and in fact doesn't really make sense, since ***would*** pragmatically implies that there was *already* an accelerating decline before the possibility of "increased internet revenue" offsetting that decline became a consideration.

Comment: Agreed, but since we don't know the intent behind the sentence, I offered suggestions to more clearly convey it.